# Chrome Custom tabs not working on emulator but are working on real Android device

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an app that uses Chrome custom tabs for third party auth sign in. The problems is is that when the custom tab is asked to open the url, the tab closes as soon as it's opened on an emulator, and only stays visible for a "split second". On a real physical device, it works fine and the custom tab stays open. I have had this working on emulators previously, but as a newbie Android developer, I do not know what can be done to try and pinpoint the problem.

Is there any configuration or setup needed to make custom tabs fully functional on emulators?